# maven-war-plugin ignores delimiter with eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, maven-war-plugin

When I build my project with `mvn clean install` everything is well, but in eclipse it ignores the properties `delimiter` and `useDefaultDelimiters`.

Is there a way to fix this or maybe ignore filtering for specific profile?

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
<version>${maven.war.plugin.version}</version>                
<configuration>
    <!-- <webXml>target/web.xml</webXml> -->
    <archive>
        <manifest>
            <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
        </manifest>
        <manifestEntries>
            <Build-Branch>${scmBranch}</Build-Branch>
            <Build-Revision>${buildNumber}</Build-Revision>
            <Build-Timestamp>${maven.build.timestamp}</Build-Timestamp>
        </manifestEntries>
    </archive>
    <warSourceExcludes>
        ${excluded.war.source}
    </warSourceExcludes>
    <filters>
        <filter>../build_versions.properties</filter>
    </filters>
    <delimiters>
      <delimiter>@*@</delimiter>
    </delimiters>
    <useDefaultDelimiters>false</useDefaultDelimiters>
    <webResources>
        <resource>
            <directory>${conf.dir}/resources</directory>
            <targetPath>WEB-INF/classes</targetPath>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>${project.build.directory}/tmpResources</directory>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
            <targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.tagx</include>
                <include>**/*.vm</include>
                <include>**/*.jspx</include>
                <include>**/*.jsp</include>
                <include>**/*.java</include>
             </includes>
        </resource>
    </webResources>
</configuration>
```